# How Do I change a string in a specific line contained in a file preserving all other lines?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file that contains this information:

```
Type=OleDll
Reference=*\G{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#2.0#0#..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb#OLE Automation
Reference=*\G{7C0FFAB0-CD84-11D0-949A-00A0C91110ED}#1.0#0#..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\SysWOW64\msdatsrc.tlb#Microsoft Data Source Interfaces for ActiveX Data Binding Type Library
Reference=*\G{26C4A893-1B44-4616-8684-8AC2FA6B0610}#1.0#0#..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\SysWow64\Conexion_NF.dll#Zeus Data Access Library 1.0 (NF)
Reference=*\G{9668818B-3228-49FD-A809-8229CC8AA40F}#1.0#0#..\packages\ZeusMaestrosContabilidad.19.3.0\lib\native\ZeusMaestrosContabilidad190300.dll#Zeus Maestros Contables Des (Contabilidad)
```

I need to change the data between {} characters on line 5 using powershell and save the change preserving all other information in the file.

Comment: please, post what you have tried ... and what didn't work as wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-replace` operator to perform a regex match and string replacement.

If there is only one pair of `{}` per line, you can do the following where `.*?` matches any non-newline character as few as possible. Since by default `Get-Content` creates an object that is an array of lines, you can access each line by index with `[4]` being line 5.

```
$content = Get-Content File.txt
$content[4] = $content[4] -replace '{.*?}','{new data}'
$content | Set-Content File.txt
```

If there could be multiple `{}` pairs per line, you will need to be more specific with your regex. A positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=)` will do.

```
$content = Get-Content File.txt
$content[4] = $content[4] -replace '(?<=Reference=\*\\G){.*?}','{newest data}'
$content | Set-Content File.txt
```

For the case when you don't know which line contains the data you want to replace, you will need to be more specific about the data you are replacing.

```
Get-Content File.txt -replace '{9668818B-3228-49FD-A809-8229CC8AA40F}','{New Data}' | Set-Content
```

If there are an encoding requirements, consider using the `-Encoding` parameter on the [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) and [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6) commands.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. It worked like a charm in a static file, but the file some times change the number of lines, ¿Is there a way to search that specific line and change the information between {}?

Comment: Yes. I added the last section that will essentially do that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used your guide as a start point to build this regex and learn: `(Reference=\*\\G)[{].*?[}].*ZeusMaestrosContabilidad.*`
It works flawlessly. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(?<=(?:.*\n){4}Reference=\*\\G\{)[\w-]+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/btCPrZ/1)

Answer (score 1):

If the content of the {} is always the same you can do this:

```bsh
(Get-Content $yourfile) -replace $regex, ('{9668818B-3228-49FD-A809-8229CC8AA40F}') | Set-Content $newValue;
```

Comment: Thank you for take the time to answer, was a big help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution :

```
$Content=Get-Content "C:\temp\test.txt"
$Row5Splited=$Content[4].Split("{}".ToCharArray())
$Content[4]="{0}{1}{2}" -f $Row5Splited[0], "{YOURNEWVALUE}", $Row5Splited[2]
$Content | Out-File "C:\temp\test2.txt"
```

Comment: I used your structure as a start point to build up the script, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to find,

```
(.*Reference=\*\\G{)[^\r\n}]+
```

and replace with,

```
$1any_thing_you_like_to_replace_with
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/L45jOA/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/L45jOA/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---